# Returns empty result

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following function:

```
public function get_interesses() {
    global $db;
    $interesses = array();
    $get_interesses = $db->query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM inter_list LEFT JOIN inter_user_conn ON inter_list.idinter = inter_user_conn.idinter AND inter_user_conn.iduser=%s WHERE inter_user_conn.idinter IS NULL", secure($this->_data['user_id'], 'int') )) or _error(SQL_ERROR_THROWEN);
    if($get_interesses->num_rows > 0) {
        while($interesse = $get_interesses->fetch_assoc()) {
            $interesses[] = $interesse;
        }
    } 
    return $interesses;
}
```

It works fine, but I want to echo the "idinter" value of the "inter_list" table, and return the empty result.
I can echo all table values except "idinter", and I need that value.

Inter List table:

[image: Inter List table]

inter_user_conn:

[image: inter_user_conn]

Comment: can you provide result of var_dump($get_interesses) ?

Comment: This function is used to display the result in Smarty Templates.     {foreach from=$user->get_interesses() item=interesse}
     <span class="interest js_add-interest" data-handle="add-interest" data-id="{$interesse['intername']}" >{$interesse['intername']}</span>
    {/foreach}